# How to pass arguments to a bash script in my c program via popen()?

Tags: linux, bash

In my c program, I want to launch a script by popen().

like this:
char mimetype[256];

//give mimetype a value

popen("xdg-mime query default some-mime-type", "r");

Is it possible to pass "some-mime-type" as an argument from c program to the bash command?

Great thanks!

Amanda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure:

```
char cmd[1024]

snprintf(cmd, sizeof(cmd), "xdg-mime query default %s", somemime_variable);
popen(cmd, "r");
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems no way to do this. I'll try to use pure shell script, no the c code.